# Reading thread's fields from synchronized event handler

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety, delphi-xe7

Is it safe to read a thread object's fields from an event handler called by the `Synchronize` procedure?

**For example:**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  public
    Max : Integer;
    Position : Integer;
    OnPositionChanged : TNotifyEvent;
    procedure Execute(); override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ProgressBar1: TProgressBar;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure MyOnPositionChanged(Sender : TObject);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

var
  Th : TMyThread;

procedure TMyThread.Execute();
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    //doing stuffs
    Sleep(500);

    //position + 1
    Inc(Position);

    //event handler
    if(Assigned(OnPositionChanged)) then
    begin
      Synchronize(
        procedure()
        begin
          OnPositionChanged(Self);
        end
      );
    end;

    //check for reaching the max value
    if(Position = Max)
    then Terminate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //preparing thread
  Th := TMyThread.Create(True);
  Th.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  Th.Max := ProgressBar1.Max;
  Th.Position := ProgressBar1.Position;
  Th.OnPositionChanged := MyOnPositionChanged;

  //starting thread
  Th.Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.MyOnPositionChanged(Sender : TObject);
begin
  //updating progressbar
  ProgressBar1.Position := (Sender as TMyThread).Position;
end;

end.
```

I'm wondering if there could be some thread-safety problem in reading the thread's fields from the main thread while the other thread is running

Comment: So long as only one thread is writing, and the integer variable is aligned, then it's safe to have many threads reading, with no synchronisation anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is generally safe. The thread's `Execute()` method is blocked while `Synchronize()` is running, so the thread won't be updating the fields while the main thread is using them.

Where this can break down is if you happen to have *another* thread updating the same fields *without* `Synchronize()`'ing access to them.